# order/invoice email is not sent from magento 1.8.0

Tags: php, magento

I installed the magento 1.8.0 version on our server and enabled the sales emails from admin panel.

I also enabled the `system -> configuration -> advanced -> system -> mail sending settings`

I have also tried by commenting email scheduling related code in Template.php file, but the email is not sent for order/invoice.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: is other mails sending ? means reset password or login emails ?

Comment: Have you added cron.sh file to crontab on server?

Comment: reset password or login emails are also not sending , cron.sh file is in the root folder

Comment: @Kingshuk  cron.sh and cron.php file is in the magento root folder

Comment: Yes i know that. Please add those files in your server crontab.

Comment: could you please provide the location/path  of server crontab in hostgator, where i have to put cron.sh file ?

Comment: i set the cron jobs on my cpanel pointing to cron.php file but no use, still magento is not sending any emails!!!

Comment: i also tested that cron.sh and cron.php is perfectly running using this link :-    http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento    , but even my magento store is not sending any email